# How to calculate distance between binary message?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a project in which I need to find the distance between binary messages. eg distance between 0001 and 1010. In decimal system distance between 1 and 1010 is 9 as (10-1). So I was wondering is there any formula for such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

1. One possibility is the [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance). In short: the Hamming distance of two equal length strings (could be binary as in your case) is the number of positions with different characters.
2. Another one is the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). In short: Levenshtein distance of two strings is the minimum number of operations (character insertions, deletions, substitutions) required to to transform one string to the other.
3. The [Damerau–Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance) is similar to the Levenshtein distance with one difference: the Levenshtein distance allows only the above three single character operation, and the Damerau–Levenshtein distance allows also the transposition of adjacent characters.

Answer (score -1):

You can use binary values directly in Python and they support arithmetic operations:

```
>>> 0b0001 - 0b1010
```

This will evaluate to -9. If you want the positive distance, you can use the abs() function to remove the signing.